# Simple PHP Contact Form - 2 Days of Pain

Tags: php, html, forms

I have no real experience with PHP, and so have just pulled bits of code from various answers to help construct a simple PHP contact form. I have spent two days trying to work out why various variations aren't working. I've included my code:

HTML :

```
    <section class="form-section" id="form-section">
    <div class="row headline">
        <h3>Free Quotation</h3> </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="htmlform" class="contact-form" target="_blank">
            <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                <div class="row inputs">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" required="" type="text"> </div>
                <div class="row inputs">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Your email" required="" value="" type="email" class="required email"> </div>
                <div class="row inputs">
                    <label for="business_name">Business Name</label>
                    <input value="" name="business_name" placeholder="Your business name" required="" type="text" class=""> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-2 message-box-container">
                <label class="text-box-label" for="message">In a few words, what are you looking for?</label>
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-messages">
                <?php 
                       if($_GET['success'] == 1) {
                    echo "<div class="success">Thank You! We'll aim to follow up as soon as possible</div>";
                       }

                    if($_GET['success'] == -1) {
                    echo "<div class="error">Oops something went wrong, please try again</div>";
                    }
                    ?> </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <div class="clear">
                    <input type="submit" value="Find Out More" name="subscribe" class="button"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my mailer.php form:

```
<?php

    // Get the form fields, removes html tags and whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $business_name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["business-name"]));
    $business_name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$business_name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check the data.
    if (empty($name) empty($business_name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: http://www.thegreenbuddha.co.uk/index.php?success=-1#form");
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address. Update this to YOUR desired email address.
    $recipient = "chussell@thegreenbuddha.co.uk";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
    $email_content .= "Business Name: $business_name \n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

    // Redirect to the index.html page with success code
    header("Location: http://www.thegreenbuddha.co.uk/index.php?success=1#form");

?>
```

When I have this on live preview both success and error messages display with PHP code. I have the file saved as a index.php. And when I submit it opens up the fresh page which is blank.

When I've added the new index.php and mailer.php to my cpanel, my website no longer displays!

Any suggestions or improvements?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why should we debug bits of code you borrowed from various places. **HIT THE BOOKS**

Comment: You have syntax errors, one example `echo "<div class="success">Thank You! `...

Comment: In `mailer.php`  after `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check for all possible errors

Comment: ^^ Same for the other file too.

Comment: `empty($foo) empty($bar)` Missing an OR there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following

```
<?php 
    if($_GET['success'] == 1) {
       echo "<div class="success">Thank You! We'll aim to follow up as soon as possible</div>";
    }
    if($_GET['success'] == -1) {
        echo "<div class="error">Oops something went wrong, please try gain</div>";
    }
?>
```

Into

```
<?php 
     if($_GET['success'] == 1) {
        echo '<div class="success">Thank You! We\'ll aim to follow up as soon as possible</div>';
     }
     if($_GET['success'] == -1) {
         echo '<div class="error">Oops something went wrong, please try gain</div>';
      }
 ?>
```

The following

```
if (empty($name) empty($business_name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  header("Location: http://www.thegreenbuddha.co.uk/index.php?success=-1#form");
  exit;
}
```

Into

```
if (empty($name) || empty($business_name) || empty($message) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  header("Location: http://www.thegreenbuddha.co.uk/index.php?success=-1#form");
   exit;
}
```

Please change the following also:

```
$business_name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["business-name"]));
```

Into

```
$business_name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["business_name"]));
```

Comment: Thanks, this has enabled my form to display on my site. When I enter the form and hit submit with correct data, it then takes me to the mailer.php and doesnt display my success or error messages... I have got the following error messages on mailer.php: Notice: Undefined index: business-name in /public_html/mailer.php on line 8

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/mailer.php:8) in /public_html/mailer.php on line 15

Comment: please change "business-name" into "business_name" and check let me know..

Comment: @CallumHussell Welcome :-)